# Unexpected reply to "Alles gut?"

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german, spoken-language

Today I asked a colleague if everything is ok, "Alles Gut?" I was expecting a usual "gut, und dir?"
But the response was unexpected and I didn't understand it. It was something like "Vol auf" or "Faul auf", please don't mind the spelling, just trying to imitate the sound of it.
Any chances someone knows what is it exactly and what it means?

Comment: I wouldn't want to speculate in an answer, but "alles wohlauf" is a standard answer when you're asking about general well-being of the family.

Answer (score 4):

We can only speculate - and the original speaker is the best source to clarify what they meant.

Wording similar to what you provide:

[vollauf](https://www.dict.cc/?s=vollauf) - completely, fully, entirely

Comment: Not convincing.

Comment: Most convincing to me. Better than the comment, which added 2 syllables.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to @planetmakers answer it could be

> wohlauf

which means as much as "healthy" and "in good good condition".

I concur with the rest of his answer: we can only speculate and the original speaker would be the best source of clarification.